pandas module not able to find table although it is present on webpage
here is my code from jupyter lab. I am trying to get pandas to output the "Advanced Receiving" table the same way that it does the Advanced passing but I keep getting this error "ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Advanced Receiving'". Here is the page with all tables https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/buf/2023_advanced.htm
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


standings_url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2023/index.htm"



data = requests.get(standings_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)

standings_table1 = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]
standings_table2 = soup.select('table.stats_table')[1]
links1 = standings_table1.find_all('a')
links2 = standings_table2.find_all('a')
all_links = [l.get('href') for l in links1] + [l.get('href') for l in links2]
team_links = [l for l in all_links if '/teams/' in l]

base_url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com"
full_team_links = [base_url + l for l in all_links]
full_team_links

team_url = full_team_links[0]
data = requests.get(team_url)
data.text

import pandas as pd
games = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Schedule & Game Results")
games[0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html5lib')
links = soup.find_all('a')
links =[l.get("href") for l in links]
links = [l for l in links if l and '/2023_advanced.htm' in l]
links

data = requests.get(f"https://www.pro-football-reference.com{links[0]}")
data.text

passing = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Advanced Passing")[0]
receiving = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Advanced Receiving")[0]
passing.head()
receiving.head()

checked if there was dynamic content loading, checked if i had incorrect table logic

You said you checked if there was dynamic content loading, but that's exactly what the problem is.  Have you done a View Source in your browser?  I don't mean examining the DOM, I mean the Ctrl-U option.  That's what requests sees.  There is no table.  There's a Javascript array that will get converted to a table later.

@TimRoberts that's not entirely true. The tables are in the View Source, just within the comments so pandas (beautifulsoup) doesn't parse it. Simple remove the comment tags or iterate through the Comment to get the tables.

tables in comments, so u can do like this(i haven't tested it, but it should work.):
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd


r = requests.get('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/buf/2023_advanced.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for comment in soup.findAll(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    table = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'lxml').find('table', {'id': 'advanced_receiving'})
    if table:
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))
        print(df)

